# Preventing JScrollPane to extend its viewPort component

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, flowlayout, componentlistener

I have a subPanel to which I occasionally add some components. I expect FlowLayout to layout them correctly. I put the subPanel in a JScrollPane to let the user see all the components but I wouldn't like to bother the user scrolling horizontally. But the JScrollPane lets subPanel extend itself horizontally when more componets are added. In this way all the components are shown in a line horizontally. And this means the worst possible layout.

```
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    subPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    subPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 4000));
    subPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    subPane = new JScrollPane(subPanel);
    subPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    subPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    this.add(subPane);
```

Somewhere else I have added a componentListener to solve the problem but the problem persists:

```
        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            subPanel.setSize(getSize());
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            subPanel.setSize(getSize());
        }
```

And `this` is a JPanel that is posed entirely in a JTabbedPane so it occupies all the tab.

Comment: Don't use a ComponentListener to play with sizes. A layout manager will manage the preferred size of the component which in turn will allow the scroll pane to work properly.

Comment: Can you tell me please which layout does JScrollPane use for posing its unique component inside? The problem is that the layout of the component inside the JScrollPane isn't managed! So I disagree but I welcome a better solution. @camickr

Comment: A JScrollPane has a custom layout mananger and you would never change it. The layout manager is responsible for managing the viewport, the scrollbars and the column and row headers. All you need to do is make sure that the component you add to the scrollpane uses a layout manager and I already gave you a suggestion on which one to use.

Comment: Testing wrapLayout I got convinced that it works and the problem is the FlowLayout capacity in calculating the component size. I wonder if it could be a bug of FlowLayout or not. @camickr

Comment: There's no bug in FlowLayout. To be blunt the bug is in your understanding of FlowLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), which will wrap components to the next line when the horizontal space is filled.

Comment: @puk: this is the one I was referring to in the comment to my answer.

Comment: @camickr I found the problem. Anyway FlowLayout wraps automatically when I resize when I resize the window. So I don't need this third party layout.

Comment: @puk, Yes it wraps but it doesn't calculate the preferred size correctly so the scrollbars won't work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> In this way all the components are shown in a line horizontally. And this means the worst possible layout.

But that's exactly what FlowLayout is supposed to do and is exactly what it does.

Why not simply use a BoxLayout oriented to BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS

Comment: The worst answer I could have! I say it is the worst layout if the components go all horizontally or vertically. They should fill all the visible space and when there is no space they must prefer to extend the panel in the vertical direction. If you have a look at [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/FlowLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/FlowLayoutDemo.java) you understand that FlowLayout isn't supposed to do what you say. I recommand to run the example to see what I mean.

Comment: @puk: `"The worst answer I could have!"` -- yikes, I've just been put in my place! It sounds like you want to either create a custom layout that does what you want (I've heard that it's not terribly hard to do, but I've never done this myself), or search for one that has been created that can do this. Rob camick (user camickr on this site) has some clever layouts that you could search for.

Comment: I don't need to search for a layout. While you were commenting I edited my answer. FlowLayout is perfect for me and it works well. I just need to add a scrollPane to let user see the components going out of viewport. @Hovercraft